# Variation Amongst Arrays

Tags: arrays, conceptual

I have several items(topics) each featuring several sub-items, as outlined below...

**Application**

- microsoft word
- excel
- visual studio

**DB**

- mysql
- mssql

I want to compare several of these groups and give a score to each topic based on how many subitems are in their respective topic compared to how many are in the other topics, ideally on a scale of 1 - 10. This is just conceptual, no specific languge. I would want to compare arrays, I just don't know how to compare every single array with all others and come up with a score after the fact. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to computing [unions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29). Most modern languages implement data types to help with this. Python has dictionaries and sets, C++ has STL maps and sets, etc. I would avoid doing any manual computation of unions, as the provided data types are much more efficient at doing it. Each topic can be thought of as a set of sub-topics, and the union of these sub-topics will determine how many are in common (i.e. in each topic).

If you are wanting to find scores between each item (topic), and if you nave n topics, you will be computing n(n - 1) / 2 scores. Just be aware that as the number of topics increases, the number of computed scores will quickly rise.

As to computing a score, you will find a union between set A and set B. This union can either

- Contain all items (meaning A and B had the exact same set); score of 10
- Contain all of 1 set (meaning B contains all of A, or vice versa) score depending on how many items unique to one set
- Contains less than the minimum size of either A or B

So a simple computation may be

```
(union.length / max(A.length, B.length)) * 10
```

Comment: If you are wanting to compare all sets, you can compute a union of all topics, and compute a score based on which one contains the least number of items not in the union.